# Being not able to expand the screen on youtube with python and selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
                    
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yjO6yfHLcU&ab_channel=TRT%C4%B0zleTRT%C4%B0zleDo%C4%9Fruland%C4%B1") #the website
 


element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ytpsize-button ytp-button"))) 
# for maximize window
element.click()
```

Hello friends, I want to expand the video screen but I couldn't do that. I wonder that How can I do this?  Is there any other solution to do this?
when I run the code it sometimes waits for ads then nothing happens
sometimes it gives a time-out error.

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException
```

Comment: Where is that maximize button ?

Comment: ".ytpsize-button ytp-button"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hover on the Menu bar first and then click on Maximize window button :

**Sample code :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yjO6yfHLcU")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ytp-chrome-controls")))).perform()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.ytp-fullscreen-button.ytp-button"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: launch the browser in full screen first using selenium and then use this code.